# How do I solve level 7 category "normal" on Lineum?

Tags: lineum

[image]

All the stone going around the green and the blue has uneven amount. Plus I keep getting bored trying to figure it out but keep getting the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

[image]

I had to leave the last tile out to take the screenshot.